# Issue with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a dynamic variable in javascript within a for each loop.
This is my code:

```
var thumbnails = jQuery('.big img');
var $counter= 0;
var test = [];
  thumbnails.each(function() {
       $counter += 1;
    var test[$counter] = $(this).attr('src');
    alert(test[$counter]);
  });
```

So as you can see I'm incrementing the $counter variable by one with each item and then I'm trying to attach that value to the test variable. However, I'm getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Comment: `var test[$counter]`

Comment: avoid using again ```var test[$counter]```, use this: ```test[$counter] = $(this).attr('src')```

Comment: @PranavCBalan if you check my code that's what I did but causes an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont's use `var` while array initialization.

```
var thumbnails = jQuery('.big img');
var $counter= 0;
var test = [];
  thumbnails.each(function() {
    $counter += 1;  
    test[$counter] = $(this).attr('src');
    alert(test[$counter]);
  });
```